# Mapa mostrando que existe sem existir

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou com um problema um tanto quanto estranho, adicionei um mapa por kml no site mas ai depois fui tentar mudar esse mapa por outro, reparei que não mudava, limpei a cache e fiz tudo porém não muda, depois deletei o kml do site e ainda assim ele diz que o caminho existe e mostra o mapa normalmente. Alguém sabe oque pode estar acontecendo? Ali em src esse caminho nem existe mais, chamo ele dentro de kmlLayer deletei o map.kml e a pasta map e ainda assim mostra o mapa

```
   var map;
var src = '<?php echo $template_directory."/assets/map/map.kml"; ?>';
function initMap(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapIndex'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
});

var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
});

 kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(kmlEvent) {
          var text = kmlEvent.featureData.id;
         switch(text){
            case 'ge1aada206d3a790b': window.location.href="www.ge1aada206d3a790b.com";
            break;

            case 'g22bdca4615d775a8': window.location.href="www.g22bdca4615d775a8.com";
            break;

            case 'g6f2fc76f6f5daa31': window.location.href="www.g6f2fc76f6f5daa31.com";
            break;

            case 'g542d4f6cf29b3da9': window.location.href="www.g542d4f6cf29b3da9.com";
            break;

            case 'g0417cd662fbf18c5': window.location.href="www.g0417cd662fbf18c5.com";
            break;

            case 'g12bf58382143fa61': window.location.href="www.g12bf58382143fa61.com"
            break;

            case 'gddd613992fbe0382': window.location.href="www.gddd613992fbe0382.com";
            break;

            case 'g81b1c174ac662941': window.location.href="www.g81b1c174ac662941.com";
            break;
         }
        })
```